# Make a UIScrollView get touch events with a UITextView as a subview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIScrollView that contains a UITextView (not editable).
I can't make the UIScrollView gets the touch events, UITextView seems to get them and keep them . Any idea how to let UIScrollView gets the touch events?

I want UITextView to still be scrollable vertically (my UIScrollView is scrollable only horizontally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `UITextView` subclass, do this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

If you want `UITextView` to handle the touches too, then I believe you can do this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

but it might result in really weird behavior.

Comment: I'd like to keep scroll enabled in the UITextView. Won't this avoid the UITextView to be scrollable? I updated my question to give more information.

Comment: It would. So you want the touches to be received by both views?

Comment: It works well! And no weird behavior, UIScrollView and UITextView behaves sa expected. Thank you!