# UITextField Is Not Scrolling Inside UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have set my UITextField to non editable and it scrolls when the text is more than what fits in the box, but I want the whole box to scroll as well, like I want everything on the page to scroll up and down even though there is no extra data off the screen, I just want the bounce there.

Do I need to add a UIScrollView for this?  I read that having a UIScrollVeiw and UITextView together can cause problems because text is a subclass of scrollview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the text view's "`Always scroll horizontally`" and/or "`Always scroll vertically`" checked.

As far as adding `UITextView` in `UIScrollView` is concerned, it might not cause problems in iOS 4.0+, but i am not sure.

You can refer to these links that deal with similar problems.
 [UITextView inside UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681708/make-a-uiscrollview-get-touch-events-with-a-uitextview-as-a-subview)